# jQuery removeClass not working with .closest method

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove parent class 'row' on the page containing id 'portfolio-page'.

```
<div class="row">  
  <div id="portfolio-page">
    <img src="sample.jpg"> 
  </div>
</div>


$('#portfolio-page').closest('.row', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('.row');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such signature as you used for [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in jquery
Try,

```
$('#portfolio-page').closest('.row').removeClass('row');
```

Just noticed this, There is no need to specify the dot with class name while using functions like `.removeClass()`/`.addClass()`/`.hasClass()`

Comment: I think np problem with code... When you are calling this code? On load or on any event...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong...

```
$('#portfolio-page').closest('.row').removeClass('.row')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.closest()` takes only one parameter, which is the selector. Read the docs here [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Correct way to do it is:

```
$('#portfolio-page').closest('.row').removeClass('.row');
```

Comment: I think when you use removeClass('.row') , no need to add dot. Just removeClass('row')